# Issues with ACF Pro v.6.0.3

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Does anyone else have problem with the newest version of ACF Pro. I have update it and now have problem with the fields. For example I have a image field where I should upload a picture but when I do that it just returns an empty value. Same is for different type of fields (text, etc.).
Is it a know bug, an update bug?

Answer (score 0):

I updated recently and did not experienced a bug like this. Could it have something to do with some settings you did in the field group?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).